# Jquery post and onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to `onclick` Jquery and post to `msg.php`. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please let me know what the problem could be. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function markAsRead(msgID) {
    var url = "msg.php";
    var ownerid = "7";
    var messageid = "msgID";
    $.post(url,{messageid: messageid, ownerid: ownerid });
}
</script>
<a onclick="markAsRead(<?php echo $row['id'];?>)">how are you?</a>
```

`

**msg.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['messageid'])) {
    $messageid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['messageid']); 
    $ownerid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['ownerid']);
    mysqli_query("UPDATE private_messages SET opened='1' WHERE id='$messageid'
LIMIT 1");
}
}
else
    echo "There is no post value";
```

Comment: @Rasclatt thank you for edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the value for `$row['id']`

```
<?php
    $row['id'] = 1; // the id is 1 for example
?>

<a onclick="markAsRead(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)">how are you?</a>

<script>
    function markAsRead(msgID) {
        var url = "msg.php";
        var ownerid = 7; // this should be unquoted
        var messageid = msgID; // this should be unquoted
        $.post(url, {
            messageid: messageid,
            ownerid: ownerid
        }, function () {
            alert('Marked!'); // added this as a callback
        }).error(function(){
            alert('Failed to mark.'); // as an error callback
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['messageid']))
    {
        $messageid = intval($_POST['messageid']); // seems your replacing numbers
        $ownerid = intval($_POST['ownerid']);  // seems your replacing numbers

        mysqli_query("UPDATE private_messages SET opened = 1 WHERE id = $messageid LIMIT 1");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is no post value";
    }
?>
```

Comment: is your **messageid** or **ownerid** a string?

Comment: the query didn't work so I put connection query...but still didin't work.

Comment: what do you mean?  "seems your replacing numbers"

Comment: The **messageid** is an integer, by using ` preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['messageid']); ` its value will be removed because your regex in `preg_replace()` matches numbers in **messageid**. I did put `intval($_POST['messageid'])` to convert it into an integer.

Comment: There is no problem with Mysql connection. but There is no `$_POST['messageid']` value.

Comment: I set the value of `$row['id']` at other part before